# .Net Core with .Net Framework Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to set the Configuration Manager AppSetting into legacy .Net Framework dependency.
The WebApi in .Net Core but for the data access have to use the legacy .Net Framework. Then Base library structure is

```
public class OracleRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public OracleRepository() : base(ConnectionString)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class BaseRepository
{
    private string _connectionString;

    public BaseRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[connectionString];
    }
}
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/

Comment: Instead of passing the name of a connection string, why don't you pass the connection string itself? Then the code responsible for creating the class (in .NET Core or .NET Framework) can use whatever way is appropriate to get the connection string.

Comment: @mason yes for legacy dll not allow to modify. The code written in dll must be reference.

Comment: In that case, you should offer an alternative constructor that accepts a connection string (perhaps in a wrapper object, call it OracleConnectionSettings or something like that). Also, your library should be moved to .NET Standard so it can properly be referenced by both .NET Core and .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly keep the repository layer in the .net framework instead of using Core.

Instead of using the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, I would suggest to inject the required settings in form of either KeyValuePair collection or Dictionary.

Then you can initialize this KeyValuePair collection or Dictionary in the startup method.

Comment: this will not solve the legacy problem. Problem is what i cannot change the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings as it is embaded in in the dll.

Comment: asp.net core does not use the system.configuration namespace.  Hence that code would not work as it is.  Please refer [this documentation on supported configurations] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2).